# Why am I getting "invalid syntax" from an f-string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error, python-3.5

I cannot get f-strings to work in Python 3. I tried this at the REPL:

```
In [1]: state = "Washington"

In [2]: state
Out[2]: 'Washington'

In [3]: my_message = f"I live in {state}"
File "<ipython-input-3-d004dd9e0255>", line 1
my_message = f"I live in {state}"
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I figured my machine was defaulting to python 2, but a quick check reveals:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.2.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
```

What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: What version of python were the others using? You seem to have answered your own question. https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals

Comment: @yeputons, avoid answering questions in the comments. Add an answer.

Comment: It's a close call, but I think the answers for the other question were slightly better overall, so I'm making that one the canonical.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

As suggested by Josh Lee in the comment section, that kind of string interpolation was added in Python 3.6 only, see [What’s New In Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals) (here it's called "[PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498): Formatted string literals").

However, you seem to be using Python 3.5.2, which does not support that syntax.

Answer (score 24):

This is a pretty old question and not sure if answered somewhere else, but ran into same problem and landed on some confusing pages. Figured out a couple of minutes later. Below line should work.

```
my_message = "I live in {}".format(state)
```

.format works for 3.5. Documenting it here for someone who may need it for similar issue.

Comment: Out of everything I tried, this was the only thing that worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score -13):

What worked for me (in python 3.8.5 in sublime) was removing the f.

```
message = "I live in {state}"
```

I find it easier than `.format(state)`

Comment: Well, it "works" in the sense that it doesn't give a syntax error... whether it does what was intended is another question.

Comment: This will not throw an error but it will not interpolate your `state` value in the string output.