# using python json object insert query

Tags: python, json, sybase

i am very new to python.. i have a json object. below is the code.

```
jsondata = json.loads(data)
```

jsondata looks like this

```
{u'approvalId': u'0', u'size-1': 202, u'indRate': u'0.003', u'orderNo': u'ROMA2-20200508-00001', u'brokerSymbol': u'', u'requestedFor': u'r101115', u'aggUnit': u'', u'repId': u'O70', u'noGoodShares': 0, u'requestedBy': u'r101115', u'status': 4, u'timestamp': u'May 08, 2020 02:29:52', u'symbol': u'IBM', u'broker': u'APOC RT', u'usedShares': 3, u'pubKey': u'O70.ROMA2-20200508-00001', u'locateBrokerId': u'APOC', u'goodShares': 500, u'rtLeafId': 900059, u'availableShares': 497, u'requestedShares': 500, u'brokerOrderNo': u'', u'indicativeRate': 0.0030000000000000001, u'pendingShares': 0}
```

i want to insert this in sybase database not all few of the details. below insert statement i tried.

```
cur = conn.cursor()

sql = "INSERT into RT24.dbo.SLOrd(status, rtLeafId, orderNo, repId, symbol, broker, timestamp, modifiedTime) VALUES (d["status"], d["rtLeafId"], d["orderNo"], d["repId"], d["symbol"\
], d["broker"], d["timestamp"], d["timestamp"])"

cur.execute(sql)
conn.commit()
```

Can someone please help me how can i do this..

Regards,
Prashant.

Comment: mistakenly i have put d. it should be jsondata.

Comment: Please format your `code`. You can edit and rectify your mistakes.

Comment: _below insert statement i tried._ What happened? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Does your current code error?

Answer (score 0):

You can't stick variables in the middle of a string like that. You should put placeholders in the SQL string, and then provide a parameters dictionary as the second argument to `cur.execute()`.

```
sql = """INSERT into RT24.dbo.SLOrd(status, rtLeafId, orderNo, repId, symbol, broker, timestamp, modifiedTime) 
        VALUES (@status, @rtLeafId, @orderNo, @repId, @symbol, @broker, @timestamp, @timestamp)"""
cur.execute(sql, {"@status": d["status"], "@rtLeafId": d["rtLeafId"], "@orderNo": d["orderNo"], "@repId": d["repId"], "@symbol": d["symbol"], "@broker": d["broker"], "@timestamp": d["timestamp"], "@timestamp": d["timestamp"]})
```

See the description of the `execute()` method in the python-sybase [manual](http://python-sybase.sourceforge.net/sybase/node10.html)

If this isn't working, you can use string formatting, but then you have the possibility of SQL-injection if you don't sanitize the data.

```
sql = f"""INSERT into RT24.dbo.SLOrd(status, rtLeafId, orderNo, repId, symbol, broker, timestamp, modifiedTime) 
        VALUES ({d["status"]}, {d["rtLeafId"]}, '{d["orderNo"]}', '{d["repId"]}', '{d["symbol"]}', '{d["broker"]}', '{d["timestamp"]}', '{d["timestamp"]}')"""
cur.execute(sql)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.. But still i am getting the error. ProgrammingError: ("Must declare variable '@status'.\n", 137).

Comment: i tried the below code and that gives me ProgrammingError: ("Incorrect syntax near '%'.\n", 102)

cur.execute("INSERT into RT24.dbo.SLOrd(rtLeafId,status,orderNo,repId,symbol,broker,timestamp)VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",(str(d["rtLeafId"]),str(d["status"]),d["orderNo"],d["repId"], d["symbol"],d["broker"],d["timestamp"]))

Comment: Sounds like you have a newline in your query string. If you want to split a Python string over multiple lines, you must use triple quotes.

Comment: Can you please give example how can I use triple quotes

Comment: i am still getting the same error
(Pdb) > /home/naikp/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/rcv.py(109)on_msg()
-> sql = """INSERT into RT24.dbo.SLOrd(rtLeafId, status, orderNo, repId, symbol, broker, timestamp) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
(Pdb) > /home/naikp/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/rcv.py(112)on_msg()
-> cur.execute(sql, (d["rtLeafId"],d["status"], d["orderNo"], d["repId"], d["symbol"], d["broker"], d["timestamp"]))
(Pdb) 0755 12:32:35>  STAT w oqsize:0, sent:2, part:0, eagain:0, full:1, forceq:5 natq:0 ffq:2 pfq:0 bytes:171
ProgrammingError: ("Incorrect syntax near '%'.\n", 102)

Comment: new code looks like this

sql = """INSERT into RT24.dbo.SLOrd(rtLeafId, status, orderNo, repId, symbol, broker, timestamp) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""

cur.execute(sql, (d["rtLeafId"],d["status"], d["orderNo"], d["repId"], d["symbol"], d["broker"], d["timestamp"]))

Comment: That looks like the syntax for the `pymysql` module, not the `python-sybase` library I linked to in my answer.

Comment: sorry i didn't get you.. any solution you gave ?

Comment: The only thing I know about using Sybase from Python is what I read in the manual I linked to, I've never done it myself. If that doesn't work, I have no other solution.

Comment: ok. but anyways thanks a lot for your help.. i learned something .. i appreciate you for helping me.

Comment: just for your info. when i try below by hardcoding the values it works for me.. 


sql = "INSERT into RT24.dbo.SLOrd(status, rtLeafId, orderNo, repId, symbol, broker, timestamp) VALUES (4, 900059, 'ROMA2-20200508-00001', 'O70', 'IBM', 'APOC RT', '2020-05-04 02:29:52')"

cur.execute(sql);

Comment: I've added a solution that uses string formatting instead of query parameters.

Comment: its throwing invalid syntax,
File "rcv.py", line 116
    sql = f"""INSERT into RT24.dbo.SLOrd(status, rtLeafId, orderNo, repId, symbol, broker, timestamp)VALUES ('{d["status"]}', '{d["rtLeafId"]}', '{d["orderNo"]}', '{d["repId"]}', '{d["symbol"]}', '{d["broker"]}', '{d["timestamp"]}')"""
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: F-strings require python 3.6 or higher. If you have an older version, use `%` or `.format()`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42126794/python-3-returns-invalid-syntax-when-trying-to-perform-string-interpolation

Comment: Hi Barmar, finally it worked. Just for you info. below is the correct query.

sql = """INSERT into RT24.dbo.SLOrd(status, rtLeafId, orderNo, repId, symbol, broker, timestamp) VALUES (%d,%d,'%s','%s','\
%s','%s','%s')""" %(d["status"],d["rtLeafId"],d["orderNo"],d["repId"],d["symbol"],d["broker"],d["timestamp"])

thank you very much. i learnt a lot