# Getting syntax error with input() function

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python. Python version which I am using is 3.8. Picture  in this link:[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8WZY.png). I am trying to run the command below:

```
name = input("Please enter your name: ")
print(f"Hello, {name}")
```

But, python gives me a syntax error when I am running the command.

```
File "/Users/Belekkanybekov/Desktop/python_work/Python.Chapter7/greeter.py", line 6
  print(f"Hello, {name}")
                       ^

Syntax Error: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What is the exact error? The code you show is fine, assuming you are using Python 3.6 or later. The error message suggests you are using an older version of Python.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow and Python!  Would you mind editing your post and writing out the error instead of linking to it?  Also, which version of Python are you running?

Comment: The syntax error isn't on the input line, it's on the print line. It's because you're using an old version of Python without f-strings.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42126794/python-3-returns-invalid-syntax-when-trying-to-perform-string-interpolation

Comment: You're not using Python 3.8.

Answer (score 1):

A `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` error occurs when you try to run your Python code with the wrong Python interpreter (`python` instead of `python3`).

```
$ python
Python 2.7.17  
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> name = input("Please enter your name: ")
Please enter your name: "Becky"
>>> print(f"Hello, {name}")
  File "", line 1
    print(f"Hello, {name}")
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Your Python version is 3.8. Your code runs correctly using the python3 interpreter which can be started with `python3`.

To run greeter.py with Python 3:

```
python3 '/Users/Belekkanybekov/Desktop/python_work/Python.Chapter7/greeter.py'
```